# Expected Value of a RV with CDF Containing a Break

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be a r.v. drawn from a cdf $F(x)$ with a support $[0,a]\cup [b,1]$, where $0< a \leq b < 1$.  $F(x)$ is continuously twice differentiable in the following intervals: $[0,a]$ and $[b,1]$; and has a break in $(a,b),$ meaning that $X$ cannot take any values in that interval.  If $b<c<1$, how do we compute the following:

$$\Pr[x \leq c]E[x|x \leq c]?$$

> My attempt: 
>   \begin{align}
> \begin{split}
> \Pr[x\leq c]E[x|x\leq c] &= \Pr[x\leq a]E[x|x\leq a] + \Pr[b\leq x\leq c]E[x|b\leq x\leq c]
> \end{split}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we have
$
\mathbb{P}[X \leq c] = F(c)
$, by definition of the cumulative distribution function ([CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Properties)).
Secondly, let us computes the expected value of $X$ under the condition $X\leq c$. To do so, we use integration by parts and the properties of the CDF:
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[X | X \leq c]
&= \int_0^a x F'(x)\, \mathrm{d}x + \int_b^c x F'(x)\, \mathrm{d}x \, ,\\
&= a F(a) - \int_0^a F(x)\, \mathrm{d}x
   + cF(c) - bF(b) - \int_b^c F(x)\, \mathrm{d}x \, ,\\
&= cF(c) + (a-b)F(a) 
   - \int_0^a F(x)\, \mathrm{d}x - \int_b^c F(x)\, \mathrm{d}x \, .
\end{aligned}